# BHyVe: Is there any way to boot to UEFI shell?

Tags: freebsd, uefi

I'm starting `BHyVe` virtual machine with UEFI firmware from ports using `chyves` and I have a problem with a boot loader misconfiguration on this particular VM.

I don't want to boot to OS in order to fix the problem with the boot loader. Instead I want to interrupt the boot process and use UEFI Shell (TianoCore?) to do all the necessary tasks before the boot loader or operating system.

The problem is that I don't know the way to invoke UEFI shell on startup in case of successful boot process and I was unable to find the information about it. Is there any way to invoke the UEFI shell in BHyVe?

Comment: AFAIK, bhyve UEFI firmware uses the UEFI default boot mechanism, i.e. it looks for the file `\EFI\BOOT\boot64.efi` in the EFI partition of your VM. If this file is not present you should end up in a EFI shell.

Comment: @fpmurphy You're right, but in case the file is found I can't boot into shell again. :(